# Data Scientist use datasource csv in tutorials, why not use connection to database?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

When I look on the internet I found a lot of tutorials about Data Scientist. 
What I have notice they all use csv as a datasource not a database connection, even you can use it.

I can't find a answer why csv, because all of my data I have are stored in a database.

What is the reason they all use csv files?

Comment: Presumably because it's easier to download and use a CSV file in a tutorial, than to walk the reader through how to set up an SQL database and connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because Data Science is all about predicting the outcome based on the the past data. Reading the directly from the database will not display accurate results because the data is being updated actively.